# What python library should I use for scripting gdb?

Tags: python, subprocess, gdb, pexpect

Hi I have been attempting to use python library functions to invoke terminal gdb in terminal on a file and input in another file and then read output(segfault or exit code) for automated debugging. I have attempted using subprocess and pexpect libraries but both do not pick up on it segmentation faulting.
pexpect library code:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("Not enough arguments, program terminated.")
    exit(1)

filename = sys.argv[1]
inputfile = sys.argv[2]

child = pexpect.spawn(f'gdb {sys.argv[1]}')
child.expect("(gdb) ")
child.sendline(f"run {sys.argv[2]}")
child.expect(["exited normally", "exited with code", pexpect.EOF])

if "exited normally" in child.before.decode('utf-8'):
    print("Program exited normally.")
else:
    print("Segmentation fault")
    child.expect("0x[0-9a-fA-F]+")
    address = child.after.decode('utf-8')
    print(f"Segfaulted at address: {address}")
```

child.close()
subprocess library code:

```
def run_gdb(filename, input_file):
    gdb_script = f"""
    run < {input_file}
    info registers
    quit
    """

    full_script = gdb_script.format(input_file)
    
    process = subprocess.Popen(['gdb', filename],
                               stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input=full_script)

    # Check if there was a segmentation fault
    if 'Segmentation fault' in stderr:
        # Extract the address from the register information
        match = re.search(r'rip\s*([0-9a-fA-F]+)', stderr)
        if match:
            faulting_address = match.group(1)
            print(f"Segmentation fault at address: {faulting_address}")
            print(f"Input string that caused the fault: {input_file}")
        else:
            print("Failed to extract address from register information.")
    else:
        print("Program exited normally.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "your_binary_file"
    input_file = "your_input_file"
    run_gdb(filename, input_file)
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the `pexpect` version you should just need to add another message to `child.expect()` to match the segmentation fault.

Comment: gdb might not be the most script friendly debugger. I'm not sure

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the python scripting capabilities of gdb itself?